# Non-discrete valuation rings of Krull dimension 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory

This seems like an elementary question but a quick Google search did not yield an answer. I know that noetherian valuation rings are discrete and that discrete valuation rings have Krull dimension 1, but I'd like to know an example of a non-discrete (necessarily non-noetherian) valuation ring with Krull dimension 1. Or an explanation why such a ring cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

Exercise $2$ in Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, ch. 6, *Valuations*, §3, explains the costruction  of a valuation ring associated to a given totally ordered group $\Gamma$.

As height $1$ ordered groups are just subgroups of the ordered group $\mathbf R$, you just have to take a non-discrete subgroup of  $\mathbf R$ for this construction, viz.  $\mathbf Q$.